# Subclassing UITableView to overlay a rectangle on the table frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**Aim:** To draw a tableview with a rectangle at the bottom (frame bottom and not the scroll bottom). I plan to use some blend mode for the rectangle. The resultant effect would be of the last row sliding from under the rectangle.
**What I Have Done:** Tried subclassing UITableView and drawing a rectangle in its drawRect(). But this draws a rectangle either above or below the table and not over it.
**Update:** Tried subclassing a `UIView` and drawing the table and rectangle inside it. But the table hides the rectangle and I have to set the table background to clear for the rectangle to be visible.
Please help.

Comment: Why you don't override UIView and put UITableView on the top and your rectangle on the bottom. Override drawRect is expensive I would recommended you to use layers.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Will try that and let know. P.S.: That was quick man!!